# VB:mouse click not work

Tags: vb.net, mouseclick-event

My codes:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
...

Private Sub Form_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        MsgBox("Right Mouse clicked.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Try to capture mouse right click, but not work.

Any suggestions welcomed. Thanks

Comment: That will work when the mouse is over an open portion of the form (meaning nor over a control, panel or whatever else).

Comment: In addition to Plutonix's comment: You have to use a global hook to capture mouse clicks outside your form. [Here's a VB.NET question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080617/intercepting-mouse-events-using-a-global-hook-stop-an-action-from-happening) containing some mouse hook code.

Answer (score 1):

As other mention in comments your code seems right, but will only work on plain form. To overcome that you can join events.

```
Private Sub Form_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseClick, Button1.MouseClick, Control1.MouseClick, AnyOtherControl.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        MsgBox("Right Mouse clicked.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Please replace Control names you want your event to fire on in this code:

```
Handles MyBase.MouseClick, Button1.MouseClick, Control1.MouseClick, AnyOtherControl.MouseClick
```

I'm guessing you are using any of container controls which fill up most of your form. If you want your event to work with them you need to add them to your event.
[image]

Finally there is also matter of `DoubleClick` which won't fire above event. To overcome it all you need to do is change `MouseClick` to `MouseDown`